# How to use the `ng-class` to add and remove the class?

Tags: angularjs

I use the ng-class to add and remove the class by clicking the ` Button,' is not does not work?  I use the Angular1.

What is the reason?

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="xxx">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>

        div {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: black;
        }
         div.red {
            background-color: red;
            }

        button   {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: gold;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body ng-controller="ooo">
<script src="angular.js"></script>

<div ng-class="{red:isRed}" >xxxx</div>

<button ng-click="changColorIsRed()">O</button>

</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('xxx',[]);
    app.controller('ooo',['$scope',function ($scope) {
        $scope.isRed = false;
        $scope.changeColor = function () {
            $scope.isRed = !$scope.isRed;
        }
    }]);
</script>
</html>
```

Is there another way to realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code.

You define function `changeColor` but you use `changColorIsRed` in your `ng-click` attribute.

If you correct this to `ng-click="changeColor()"`, your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<button ng-click="changColorIsRed()">O</button>
```

To

```
<button ng-click="changColor()">O</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one mistake in your code:

Other than below change:

```
<button ng-click="changColorIsRed()">O</button>
```

To

```
<button ng-click="changColor()">O</button>
```

You can not use Angular's directives and then load the `angular.js` file.
You must to set the below code:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

on top of `ng-app`.